# Bash - Gitlab CI not converting variable to a string

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, gitlab

I am using GitLab to deploy a project and have some environmental variables setup in the GitLab console which I use in my GitLab deployment script below:

```
- export S3_BUCKET="$(eval \$S3_BUCKET_${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME^^})"
- aws s3 rm s3://$S3_BUCKET --recursive
```

My environmental variables are declared like so:

```
Key: s3_bucket_development
Value: https://dev.my-bucket.com

Key: s3_bucket_production
Value: https://prod.my-bucket.com
```

The plan is that it grabs the bucket URL from the environmental variables depending on which branch is trying to deploy (`CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME`).

The problem is that the `S3_BUCKET` variable does not seem to get set properly and I get the following error:

```
> export S3_BUCKET=$(eval \$S3_BUCKET_${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME^^})
> /scripts-30283952-2040310190/step_script: line 150: https://dev.my-bucket.com: No such file or directory
```

It looks like it picks up the environmental variable value fine but does not set it properly - any ideas why?

Comment: Last time I checked, Gitlab used a POSIX shell and not Bash. Make sure you know the environment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to get the value of the variables `S3_BUCKET_DEVELOPMENT` and `S3_BUCKET_PRODUCTION` based on the value of `CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME`, you can do this by using parameter indirection:

```
$ a=b
$ b=c
$echo "${!a}" # c
```

and in your case, you would need a temporary variable as well, something like this might work:

```
- s3_bucket_variable=S3_BUCKET_${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME^^}
- s3_bucket=${!s3_bucket_variable}
- aws s3 rm "s3://$s3_bucket" --recursive
```

Comment: I don't understand line 2 of this solution. Should `!bucket_variable` be `!s3_bucket_variable`?

Comment: Yes it should..

Comment: This seems to trim my variable likely due to the // characters in it. Here is the error I get from AWS CLI `Invalid bucket name "https:": Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$" or be an ARN matching the regex`

Comment: It doesn't. The value is trimmed somewhere else, might be `aws` or your variable doesn't contain anything but `https:` in either case it's apparently not a valid bucket name for `aws`.

Comment: I removed https and it works fine thanks :) Bonus question: when my branch has a `/` in it it does not like assigning the variable and results in this error: `S3_BUCKET_FEATURE/TMP-1477: invalid variable name`. Works just fine if it doesn't have the `/` in it like S3_BUCKET_DEVELOPMENT

Comment: `S3_BUCKET_FEATURE/TMP-1477` is an invalid parameter name, what would you expect that should happen? In either case you wouldn't have a variable to expand, resulting in an empty string.

Comment: I would expect `S3_BUCKET_FEATURE/TMP-1477` to just be a normal string like `S3_BUCKET_DEVELOMENT` is

Comment: If that's the case then there is no need to make the indirection in the first place. Just use `$s3_bucket_variable` instead of `$s3_bucket`

Answer (score 0):

You are basically telling bash to execute command, named `https://dev.my-bucket.com`, which obviously doesn't exist.

Since you want to assign *output* of command when using `VAR=$(command)` you should probably use `echo`

```
export S3_BUCKET=$(eval echo \$S3_BUCKET_${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME^^})
```

Simple test:

```
VAR=HELL; OUTPUT="$(eval echo "\$S${VAR^^}")"; echo $OUTPUT
/bin/bash
```

It dynamically creates SHELL variable, and then successfully prints it

Comment: Or just parameter indirection, and another temporary variable: `var=HELL; var2=S$var; echo "${!var2}"`. You should never use `eval` when you can avoid it.

Comment: agreed, eval is evil, your solution is better, completely forgot about it